# Return list of matching rows

Tags: excel

Sheet1

A B C D
1 2 3 4
2 4 5 6
3 3 5 6
4 7 3 1
5 4 6 7

Sheet 2

A B C D
1 4
2 1
3 1 3 4
4 1 2 5
5 2 3
6 2 3 5
7 4 5

Column A of Sheet 2 has a non repeating listing of all values in Sheet 1.  I would like a forumla so Col B of Sheet 2 lists the value of Sheet 1 Col A for each row where the Sheet 2 Col A lookup value is found.  Either giving me a comma sep list or putting the results in sheet 2 Col B,C,D,...

Comment: I've had to do it several times on a quite large data set which was very time consuming and error prone.  That is why I was wondering if there is a way to do this with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, but it involves a handful of formulas, not just one. Hopefully, you will still find it useful.

Your Sheet2 would basically look like this:

[image: Layout of Sheet2]

Here are the formulas you need to enter:

```
B1: =IFERROR(SMALL($G4:$U4,COLUMN()-1),"")    [drag down and across to D7]
G1: =IF(F2=$W2,F1+1,MAX(1,F1))                [drag across to U1]
G2: =IF(F2=$W2,1,F2+1)                        [drag across to U2]
G3: =INDEX(Sheet1!B$1:D$5,G1,G2)              [drag across to U3]
G4: =IF(G$3=$F4,G$1,"")                       [drag down and across to U10]
```

What this does is organize the Sheet1 data into rows, where each row corresponds to a lookup value. Then, it grabs the smallest value, the second smallest value (if one exists), and third smallest value (if one exists) from each row.

This should be easy to scale to as large a spreadsheet as you need (as long as you don't run out of columns).